# Automatically change cell content based on content in cell - Xcode 9.2 Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a table View in a View Controller, and within the cells, my text gets cut off when it's too long. How do I get the cell to automatically change based on the content in the cell or get the text to wrap so the text doesn't get cut off? Here's an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hN7kB.png) of what I'm talking about.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    return 50
}

func allowMultipleLines(tableViewCell: UITableViewCell) {
    tableViewCell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
    tableViewCell.textLabel?.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return courses.count
}


 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let course:UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "course")!

    course.textLabel?.text = courses[indexPath.row]

    return course
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Courses", sender: nil)
}

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    let detailView: DetailCoursesViewController = segue.destination as! DetailCoursesViewController

    selectedRow = (table.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row)!

    detailView.setCourseTitle (t: courses[selectedRow])
    detailView.setCourseDescription (d: courseDescription[selectedRow])
    detailView.setCredits (c: credits[selectedRow])
    detailView.setPrerequisites (p: prereq[selectedRow])

}
```

Here is the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yu5JJ.png) of the code

Comment: Refer - https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithSelf-SizingTableViewCells.html

Comment: Along with the above link set the numberOfLines = 0 on your label.

Comment: Seems to be you are having only one label inside the cell. Set labels top, bottom, trailing and leading constraints and set the tableView.estimatedRowHeight = "//max cell height ", tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension.

Comment: I did what the site said to do, but It's not wrapping the text to a new line within the cell.

Comment: @CoryT87 Did you set the label.numberOfLines = 0 ?

Comment: @SHISHIRRAMIN I've added my code for you to take a look at. You can see that I have the allowMultipleLines function, but it's not dropping the text down to a new line within the cell when it gets cut off.

Comment: tableView.estimatedRowHeight = "//max cell height ", tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension are missing

Comment: where am i suppose to put that at?

Comment: @CoryT87 Inside override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

   tableView.estimatedRowHeight = "//max cell height ", tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension 
}

Comment: I keep getting this error: Ambiguous reference to member 'tableView(_:heightForRowAt:)'

Comment: @CoryT87 remove tableView(_:heightForRowAt:) method

Comment: @CoryT87 since you are using estimatedRowHeight, there is no need to explicitly return the height for each tableViewCell

Comment: When I do that it's basically having me remove all the functions heightForRow and down

Comment: @CoryT87 could you update the code. what is the error your getting now?

Comment: I've added an image at the bottom of the code. The code that is blocked out is what I was getting an error on so I blocked it out.

Comment: Did you create the pointer of tableView. Looks like you have not defined it.

Comment: @CoryT87 I have added the answer for your reference .Please look at it. let me know if it works well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to set **leading, trailing, bottom and top constraints** of label to contentView in the TableViewcell.

```
     override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tabelView.estimatedRowHeight = 50
        self.tabelView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
       return courses.count
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

       let course:UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "course")!
       cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0
       course.textLabel?.text = courses[indexPath.row]

       return course
    }
```

Comment: It's not letting me add any constraints other than what I already have. I'm still getting this error:
`Ambiguous reference to member 'tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)' `

Comment: @CoryT87 can I have an access to your code ?. Look like It's not finding tableView.

Answer (score 1):

1) Set `UILabel property numberOfLines = 0` inside `cellForRowAt` of `UITableView`

2) Inside `ViewDidLoad` write below code

```
self.tabelView.estimatedRowHeight = 44
self.tabelView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

[Demo Example](https://github.com/paresh1994/TableViewDynamicCellSize)

Comment: I took a look at your demo. When I run the project, it doesn't return any text within the cell.

Answer (score 0):

1- Give a bottom constraint between the label and cell bottom like 10

2- In the function `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` do the following:

```
cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0
cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
```